# Convert php restapi call to node axios

Tags: node.js, axios

I try to rewrite a php rest api post from php curl to node axios.

Everything I have tried result in a 401 response, 200 is expected for success.

PHP is:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    $restquery = "https://xxx/v2.2/apis/asset/category/list"

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $restquery);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $headerpart1 = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
    $headerpart2 = "Authorization: Bearer ".$token;

    $headers = array(
        $headerpart2,
        $headerpart1,
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $body = array();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

I tried with node

```
    var headerpart1 = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8';
    var headerpart2 = 'Authorization: Bearer '+token;

    var authhead =  { headerpart1, headerpart2 };

    return axios.get("https://xxx/v2.2/apis/asset/category/list", { headers: authhead });
```

I also tried:

```
    var headerpart1 = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8';
    var headerpart2 = 'Authorization: Bearer '.concat(token);

    var authhead =  { headerpart1, headerpart2 };


    return axios.request({
        url: "/v2.2/apis/asset/category/list",
        method: "GET",
        baseURL: "https://xxx/",
        headers: authhead
    });
```

I also tried some other ways but I always receive 401. The Token is definitely generated with success so it have to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

ok, after some more research I use:

```
const config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://xxx/v2.2/apis/asset/category/list',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '.concat(token)
    }
}
console.log(config);
return axios(config);
```

And it works perfect.